# Derefencing a pointer to a struct in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, dereference

I'm new to C++ and am trying to figure out how to dereference a pointer to a struct, so that I can retrieve the values of the members in that struct.  In buildCar(), I'd like to be able to print the year of the car as well as the specs of the car (which, when set, will be a pointer to another structure).  I'm able to print out the memory address where the car1 struct is stored, but I'm having trouble figuring out the correct syntax to use to deference this pointer.  I've tried using (*) for derefencing, and -> instead of . to refer to the struct's members, but have had no luck thus far.  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you!

```
struct item {
  int id;
  void *myData;
};

 struct car {
  unsigned int year;
  char* specs;
};

void buildCar(item item1);

int main() {
  struct item item1;
  item1.id = 1;
  struct car car1;
  car1.year = 2019;
  item1.myData = &car1;
  buildCar(item1);
}


void buildCar(item item1){
cout << "address of car1  = " << item1.myData;
}
```

Comment: `struct item item1;` is something you would see in C. In C++ you can just write `item item1;`. The compiler already knows that `item` is a type name.

Comment: `myData` is a `void*` which you can't really do much with except cast back to the original pointer type. Seems like `myData` should be a `car*` instead of a `void*`.

Comment: Every time you see `void` in a C++ program, you should think there is probably something wrong.

Comment: @NeilButterworth What about `void` return type? Maybe you meant `void*`.

Comment: @ François That's why I said "probably" - a function that only has side-effects is mostly (but not always) not a good function.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Erm, what? What should e.g. `std::vector::push_back()` return? Or `std::thread::detach`? Or `std::lock`? Or...? `void`-returning functions are absolutely normal.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I don't know if I've ever disagreed more with a comment on this site before. I agree `void*` is code smell, but `void` functions are *not* a bad sign. Not even a little bit. Let's just start by counting how many `void` functions [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) might contain. Which one of those are "not a good function"? How would you improve them?

Comment: To clarify, the item struct is actually defined in a C header file (.h), but I need to use that struct in my C++ program.  For simplicity, I included it as all part of 1 program for this question.  Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @NeilButterworth Yeah, but even with the equivocating "probably" I disagree completely. It's not at all rare, it's common and normal.

Comment: @François  Well, not in the code I write.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Well, that's up to you. But it's not a guideline that you can apply in general.

Comment: @François Just let me get this right - you are saying side-effects are a good thing and not something to be avoided?

Comment: @NeilButterworth If the purpose of a function is to modify an object, then it's acceptable for that function to have the side effect of modifying the object in the intended way. Let's not try to insinuate that this is promoting side effects in general. `std::sort` is expected to modify the range you pass it. It's not bad that it does this.

Comment: @NeilButterworth this is getting pretty off topic but whether you should prefer to program in an imperative or functional style is a debate of its own. C++ simply lets you do both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm having trouble figuring out the correct syntax to use to deference this pointer.

You cannot indirect through a void pointer. You can only indirect through non-void pointers.

A solution: Change the type of the pointer:

```
struct item {
    int id;
    struct car *myData;
};
```

You can then access the members of the pointed object using the indirecting member access operator `->`.

> Presumably there could be other types of items than cars, so a void * might be necessary.

In pure C++, there are better alternatives such as inheritance, `std::variant` and `std::any`, depending on usage requirements.

Given that Mango mentioned in a comment that the header is C, the better alternatives might not be available, and `void*` may be necessary indeed.

In such case, the void pointer can be converted back to the original pointer type which the void pointer was converted from using `static_cast`. The behaviour of converting to a wrong type will be undefined, so great care must be taken.

Comment: Presumably there could be other types of items than cars, so a `void *` might be necessary.

Comment: @stark I edited the answer to take that into consideration.

Comment: Thank you for the potential solution.  I am not able to make changes to the C header file that contains the item struct definition, and yes, myData can point to other items besides a car, so I'll have to continue using void*.  Would you mind elaborating further on how I can use static_cast to perform this conversion?  Perhaps an example?

Comment: @eerorika Nevermind, I figured it out.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: car* carPointer = static_cast<car*>(item1.myData);
cout << "year of car1  = " << carPointer->year << endl;

Answer (score 0):

So, let's start from one of the basics: in C++ structs are classes that default to public.

What you have looks like C, so I'm going to assume that is your foundational language.

That means you have access to the full breadth of class behavioral configuration in a struct.

Thus you can rewrite it something like:

```
struct Car {
    unsigned int year;
    char* specs;

    Car(int year) : year(year) {} //Constructor
};

struct Item {
    int id;
    Car *myData;

    Item(int id, Car* car) : id(id), myData(car) {} // Constructor
    ~Item() { delete myData; } // Destructor. This prevents a potential data leak.
    void buildCar() { std::cout << "address of car1  = " << myData; } // Member Function
};

int main() {
    Item item1(1, new Car(2019));
    item1.buildCar();

}
```

If you're wondering what some of those things are, look for Constructor syntax, Constructor initializer lists, and the `new` operator, they're pretty essential to C++.